How can I solve the partition is full when it is not
I am trying to copy a disk with several partitions to another formatted disk.
When I use a disk copying software, e.g. Minitool Partition Wizard, and when it starts copying drive c, it stops with the following error:
NTFS file system error:
Please use Check file system to fix error
I'v tried the following several times, to no avail:
chkdsk /r (and restarted the pc)
sfc/scannow

But I noticed something that could point to the cause of the problem.
Using both "Disk Management" and "Diskpart" on Windows:
Total size = 54.9 GB
Free space = 40.7 GB

The above figures are correct.
However, the minitool displays this:
Total size = 54.9 GB
Unused = 0 GB
Adjacent volume:
Total size =388 GB
Unused =281 GB

The next adjacent volume:
Total size =22 GB
Unused =15 GB

For some reason, it considers the partition as full, when it's not.
What is a solution to this problem?

Minitool basically says that your drive is 54.9 GB big, and that there is no unpartitioned space. This has nothing to do with the free space available inside a partition.

I'm not sure if that is the case. Minitool  displays other drives on the same disl.  It does details total size and unused space on each.  I will try to edit the post with an added image.

You shouldn't try copying a mounted partition.  You will always get errors that way.

– LPChip: sorry I couldn't add an image. However, I have added the values of 2 adjacent volumes to the original post.

user10489: It's not mounted.  I have used the same procedure many times before without a problem.  The real  issue here is that the volume is reported as full when it is not full.

There is "talk" on various forums about using diskpart and "extend partition" or "extend filesystem" to resolve similar issues.  Does anyone know if they would affect data on the disk?

Any work on a drive has the potential to damage/lose data on that drive. The correct course of action is to take a full backup of all the data on the drive prior to doing any work. This also frees you to be more active in your own work to resolve this, as you won't have to worry about losing data.

I tried some suggestions found on the net and a number of other disk/partition copying software without success.  Eventually I found one that worked.  It copied the entire disk and resolved the problem.
Thank you all for your input.
